# Настроить add_rewtire_rule для пагинации архива терма пользовательской таксономии wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, rewrite, роутинг

Есть пользовательская таксономия - taxcompanies. Есть архивы термина (т.е. разделы рубрики), один из них например mashinostroenie.

URL для архива термина выглядит вот так **/taxcompanies/mashinostroenie/**.
Постраничная навигация работает нормально. Ссылка на 2 страницу архива выглядит так: **/taxcompanies/mashinostroenie/page/2/**.

С помощью фильтра удалил название таксономии из URL:

```
function taxonomy_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy ) {
if ( $taxonomy !== 'taxcompanies' )
    return $link;
return str_replace( 'taxcompanies/', '', $link );
```

}
`add_filter( 'term_link', 'taxonomy_link', 10, 3 );`

и добавил правило для роутинга:

```
function taxonomy_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxcompanies=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'taxonomy_rewrite_rule');`
```

после чего слаг **taxcompanies** из URL на страницы термов исчез,
и он теперь выглядит например вот так **/mashinostroenie/**. Страницы открывают нормально, проблем нет.

Только перестала работать постраничная навигация, переходя например по **/mashinostroenie/page/2/** вылетает 404 ошибка, страница не найдена. Если вручную добавить в начало имя таксономии,**/taxcompanies/mashinostroenie/page/2/**, тогда 2 страница открывается нормально.

Пробовал добавить правило в add_rewrite_rule

```
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?taxonomy=taxcompanies&term=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Но все равно возникает 404 ошибка при открытии 2 страницы пагинации.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить add_rewtire_rule

Регистрация таксономии:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_companies', 0 );

function create_companies() {
$args = array(
    'label' => _x( 'Категории предприятий', 'taxonomy general name' ), // Название таксономии во множественном числе для перевода. По 
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Категории предприятий', 'taxonomy general name' ), 
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Категория предприятий', 'taxonomy singular name' ), 
        'menu_name' => __( 'Категории предприятий' ), 
        'all_items' => __( 'Все категории предприятий' ), 
        'view_item' => __( 'Просмотреть категорию предприятий' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить категорию предприятий' ), 
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить новую категорию предприятий' ), 
        'new_item_name' => __( 'Название' ), 
        'parent_item' => __( 'Родительская' ), 
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Родительская:' ), 
        'search_items' => __( 'Поиск категорий предприятий' ),
        'popular_items' => null, 
        'separate_items_with_commas' => null, 
        'add_or_remove_items' => null, 
        'choose_from_most_used' => null, 
        'not_found' => __( 'Категорий предприятий не найдено.' ), 
    ),
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
    'show_tagcloud' => true, 
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true, /
    'meta_box_cb' => null, 
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'description' => '', 
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'update_count_callback' => '', 
    'query_var' => true, 
    // Перезапись URL. По умолчанию: true.
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'taxcompanies', // Текст в ЧПУ. По умолчанию: название таксономии.
        'with_front' => true, // Позволяет ссылку добавить к базовому URL.
        'hierarchical' => true, // Использовать (true) или не использовать (false) древовидную структуру ссылок. По умолчанию: false.
        'ep_mask' => EP_NONE, // Перезаписывает конечное значение таксономии. По умолчанию: EP_NONE.
    ),
    'sort' => null, // Должна ли таксономия запоминать порядок, в котором посты были созданы. По умолчанию: null.
    '_builtin' => false, 
);
register_taxonomy( 'taxcompanies', array('companies'), $args );
```

}

Регистрация пользовательского типа данных:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_companies', 0 );
function register_post_companies() {
$args = array(
    'label'  => _x( 'Предприятия', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ), 
    'labels' => array(...),

    'description' => '', 
    'public' => true, 
    'exclude_from_search' => false, 
    'publicly_queryable' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true, 
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-textcolor', 
    'map_meta_cap' => null, // Использовать ли внутренние значения по умолчанию для управления правами. По умолчанию: null.
    'hierarchical' => false, 
    'supports' => array(
        'title', 
        'editor',
        'author', 
        'thumbnail', 
        'excerpt', 
        'trackbacks', 
        'custom-fields', 
        'comments', 
        'page-attributes',
        'post-formats', 
    ),
    'register_meta_box_cb' => null, 
    'taxonomies' => array('taxcompanies'), 
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'companies', 
        'with_front' => false, 
        'feeds' => false, // Должна ли структура постоянных ссылок быть встроена для этого типа записи. По умолчанию: значение 'has_archive'.
        'pages' => false, // Должна ли структура ссылок обеспечена быть постраничной навигацией. По умолчанию: true.
    ),
    'permalink_epmask' => EP_PERMALINK, 
    'query_var' => true, 
    'can_export' => true, 
    'delete_with_user' => null, 
    'show_in_rest' => false, 
    'rest_base' => '',
    // 'rest_base' => $post_type, // Базовый ярлык данного типа записи когда доступно использование REST API. По умолчанию: значение $post_type.
    '_builtin' => false, 
);
register_post_type( 'companies', $args );
```

}

Comment: Покажите код регистрации (register_taxonomy)

Comment: Добавил код регистрации таксономии

Comment: Так же добавил код регистрации custom post type

Comment: Я предполагаю, что в структуре url для страниц постраничной навигации учитывается имя таксономии, потому что если заходить по адресу /taxcompanies/mashinostroenie/page/2/, то все работает.  Нужно например с помощью какого-то фильтра удалить имя таксономии из ссылок на страницы пагинации. Но как это сделать я еще не нашел, или может я вообще не прав((

Comment: да я проблему понял, надо потестить у меня на сайте, чуть позже постараюсь ответить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить правило для перезаписи url не только таксономии, но и ее страниц /page/. Полный код хука выглядит так:

```
function taxonomy_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxcompanies=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule( '(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?taxcompanies=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'taxonomy_rewrite_rule');
```

Рабочий пример у меня на сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/mashinostroenie/

P.S. Не забудьте сохранить структуру постоянных ссылок в админке после изменения этого кода в functions.php

Comment: Спасибо, работает без проблем. Вообщем нужно учить регулярные выражения) Вместе Вашего выражения перед /page (.+?), у меня было ([^/]+) и из-за этого не работало)

Comment: не-не! тут ДВА выражения нужно! И не забудьте сохранить структуру постоянных ссылок в админке после изменения этого кода в functions.php